# Is there any other solution for "could not find the database engine startup handle' for MS SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

I have tried every method available online.

1. Uninstalling every MSSQL server
2. Removing keys from registry
3. Uninstalling and deleting files from program files
4. Start setup in administrator mode
5. selecting the server as nt authority system and also nt authority local service

Still I am getting that error. Please help

> 2021-05-16 18:01:59.78 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) -
> 15.0.2000.5 (X64)     Sep 24 2019 13:48:23    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home
> Single Language 10.0  (Build 18363: )
>
> 2021-05-16 18:01:59.78 Server      UTC adjustment: 5:30 2021-05-16
> 18:01:59.78 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation. 2021-05-16
> 18:01:59.85 Server      All rights reserved. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85
> Server      Server process ID is 2488. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85 Server
> System Manufacturer: 'ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.', System Model: 'GL552VX'.
> 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
> 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file
> 'F:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
> 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85 Server      The service account is
> 'WORKGROUP\PRIYANSHU$'. This is an informational message; no user
> action is required. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.85 Server      Registry
> startup parameters:    -d F:\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf   -e F:\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG      -l F:\Microsoft SQL
> Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf 2021-05-16
> 18:01:59.85 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:   -s
> "MSSQLSERVER" 2021-05-16 18:01:59.88 Server      SQL Server detected 1
> sockets with 4 cores per socket and 8 logical processors per socket, 8
> total logical processors; using 8 logical processors based on SQL
> Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is
> required. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.88 Server      SQL Server is starting at
> normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.88 Server      Detected
> 8057 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is
> required. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.88 Server      Using conventional memory
> in the memory manager. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.88 Server      Page
> exclusion bitmap is enabled. 2021-05-16 18:01:59.92 Server      Buffer
> Pool: Allocating 2097152 bytes for 1289161 hashPages. 2021-05-16
> 18:01:59.93 Server      Default collation:
> SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS (us_english 1033) 2021-05-16 18:01:59.96
> Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is
> necessary. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.02 Server      Query Store settings
> initialized with enabled = 1,  2021-05-16 18:02:00.02 Server      The
> maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this
> instance is '1' 2021-05-16 18:02:00.02 Server      This instance of
> SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 6652 at 16-05-2021
> 17:55:56 (local) 16-05-2021 12:25:56 (UTC). This is an informational
> message only; no user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.03
> Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0
> Active CPU mask: 0x00000000000000ff:0. This message provides a
> description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an
> informational message only. No user action is required. 2021-05-16
> 18:02:00.03 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial
> allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.
> This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.04 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on
> lowend machine. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.05 Server      [INFO] Created
> Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
>
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.05 Server      Database Instant File
> Initialization: disabled. For security and performance considerations
> see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server
> Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is
> required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.05 Server      Total Log Writer threads:
> 2. This is an informational message; no user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.06 Server      clflushopt is selected for pmem
> flush operation. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.06 Server      Software Usage
> Metrics is disabled. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.06 spid9s      Starting up
> database 'master'. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.28 spid9s      2 transactions
> rolled forward in database 'master' (1:0). This is an informational
> message only. No user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.31
> Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.34
> spid9s      0 transactions rolled back in database 'master' (1:0).
> This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.37 Server      Common language runtime (CLR)
> functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319. 2021-05-16
> 18:02:00.44 spid9s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.44 spid9s      SQL Server Audit is starting the
> audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.46 spid9s      SQL Server Audit has started the
> audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.47 spid9s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login
> "sa". 2021-05-16 18:02:00.48 spid9s      Server name is 'PRIYANSHU'.
> This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid25s     Always On: The availability replica
> manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user
> action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid25s     Always On: The
> availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server
> to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No
> user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid9s      Starting
> up database 'msdb'. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid14s     Starting up
> database 'mssqlsystemresource'. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid9s
> Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid9s
> FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
> d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf
> for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path
> specified.). 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid9s      Error: 5120, Severity:
> 16, State: 101. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.50 spid9s      Unable to open the
> physical file
> "d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBData.mdf".
> Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path
> specified.)". 2021-05-16 18:02:00.51 spid9s      Error: 17207,
> Severity: 16, State: 1. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.51 spid9s
> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot
> find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file
> 'd:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf'.
> Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
> operation. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.51 spid9s      File activation failure.
> The physical file name
> "d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\MSDBLog.ldf"
> may be incorrect. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.53 spid14s     The resource
> database build version is 15.00.2000. This is an informational message
> only. No user action is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.65 spid22s     A
> self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.65 spid22s     Server is listening on [ 'any'
>  1433]. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.65 spid22s     Server is listening
> on [ 'any'  1433]. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66 spid22s     Server
> local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [
> \.\pipe\SQLLocal\MSSQLSERVER ]. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66 spid22s
> Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [
> \.\pipe\sql\query ]. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66 Server      Server is
> listening on [ ::1  1434]. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66 Server
> Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1  1434]. 2021-05-16
> 18:02:00.66 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was
> established for listening locally on port 1434. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66
> spid22s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an
> informational message; no user action is required. 2021-05-16
> 18:02:00.66 Server      SQL Server is attempting to register a Service
> Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Kerberos
> authentication will not be possible until a SPN is registered for the
> SQL Server service. This is an informational message. No user action
> is required. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.66 Server      The SQL Server Network
> Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN)
> [ MSSQLSvc/priyanshu ] for the SQL Server service. Windows return
> code: 0xffffffff, state: 53. Failure to register a SPN might cause
> integrated authentication to use NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an
> informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos
> authentication is required by authentication policies and if the SPN
> has not been manually registered. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.69 Server
> The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the
> Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/priyanshu:1433 ] for the SQL
> Server service. Windows return code: 0xffffffff, state: 53. Failure to
> register a SPN might cause integrated authentication to use NTLM
> instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action
> is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by
> authentication policies and if the SPN has not been manually
> registered. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.75 spid14s     Starting up database
> 'model'. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Error: 17204, Severity:
> 16, State: 1. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     FCB::Open failed:
> Could not open file
> d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf
> for file number 1.  OS error: 3(The system cannot find the path
> specified.). 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Error: 5120, Severity:
> 16, State: 101. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Unable to open the
> physical file
> "d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\model.mdf".
> Operating system error 3: "3(The system cannot find the path
> specified.)". 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Error: 17207,
> Severity: 16, State: 1. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s
> FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(The system cannot
> find the file specified.) occurred while creating or opening file
> 'd:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf'.
> Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the
> operation. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     File activation failure.
> The physical file name
> "d:\dbs\sh\s19s\0924_133725\cmd\2\obj\x64retail\sql\mkmastr\databases\mkmastr.proj\modellog.ldf"
> may be incorrect. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Error: 945,
> Severity: 14, State: 2. 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     Database
> 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient
> memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
> 2021-05-16 18:02:00.76 spid14s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server
> shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no
> user action is required.

Comment: Could be more specific what exact error your are getting ?

Comment: The correct error should be: _Could not find the Database Engine startup handle._ Are you getting this in the SQL Server Setup program? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67543653/edit) your question to include the relevant information from the `SQLServer_ERRORLOG_<DATETIME>` log file. It often involves problems loading the master.mdf/mastlog.ldf or model.mdf/modellog.ldf files due to missing files, insufficient file system permissions (ACLs) or even volume cluster sizes/alignment.

Comment: I read one today where there was an error of insufficient file system permissions. I am reinstalling it. Will upload the errorlog too.

Comment: I was unable to solve the error so I used dock to install SSMS in my system. Thanks for the help anyways